# How to deploy existing report in MS CRM 4.0

Tags: report, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am new with MS CRM (Well.. spot the obvious.. but..) 
How can I deploy existing report in MS CRM 4.0?
I don't want to edit or create a new one. I have a .rdl file and I just want to deploy it and publish it for a custom entity.. How do I do that? There is a report wizard in which I thought I could just select my report, but I don't see it in the list there. Maybe I need to copy it to specific location or something, but I don't know where?

Thanks! 
Katya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Reports list (My Work->Reports in Workplace, I think you already found that), click "New", and then under "Report Type" choose "Existing File" which will replace the "Report Wizard" button with a file browser control to let you upload your .rdl file.